# Microsoft Office 15 Applications display errors when attempting to preview in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-registry, microsoft-office-2013, 32-vs-64-bit

In Windows Explorer (WIN 7 Pro SP1, 64-bit), if I click on a file belonging to any of the 3 Office programs that Explorer will preview in the Preview pane, I get an error, and no preview is generated.

A Word file (.docx) will display a dialog with a blue "information" icon and the text "Sorry, something went wrong and word was unable to start. (24)"

PowerPoint displays a dialog with a red "X", and states "There's not enough memory or system resources to start PowerPoint." Note: my machine has 32GB of RAM, and it doesn't matter how much of that RAM is available.

Excel displays a dialog with a red "X", but the dialog is very small, without visible text, and cannot be resized.

I can open all of these files without issue, even without dismissing the dialogs, so I suspect there's some kind of "helper" routine that's tripping on the way to engaging the application to preview the file. If that's at all how any of this works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

My machine is employer provided, and I've engaged IT support on at least 4 occasions to address the issue, and it's been escalated as far is it can, it would appear. Under their instruction, I've performed both fast and full repairs and reinstallations multiple times, but no dice.

Possible of note: I accidentally had the 64-bit version of Office installed on this machine at one point, but needed to immediately uninstall it due to several incompatibility issues. Maybe there’s some abandoned file getting tapped when I try to preview a file in Explorer that doesn’t have the rest of its resources because I uninstalled it…

Comment: Your problems are caused by the 64-bit installation you removed.  I suggest you have your IT staff reimage your system again, it should take no time at all, if they have the SOPs.  32-bit and 64-bit installations of Office conflict with one another, you have Office 2013 and Office 2015 installed together no problem, although add-on and third-party applications might not like that ( seperate matter )

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: @DavidPostill, I've reviewed /on-topic and /dont-ask, and I'm not seeing where I've run aground... This is an issue related to software and hardware. Am I missing something?

Comment: You missed the bit that says "If you have a question about … **and it is not about** … issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,"

Comment: I want to understand: is the intention of the line "issues specific to corporate IT support and networks" to indicate I shouldn't bring issues I have with hardware or software provided by my employer here? I mean, would we be having this exchange if this was my personal laptop and my own licenced installation of Office?

Comment: @Sun, thank you. I work for huge company that for sure has their own "layer" on machines, and it absolutely affects things, but again, that's not an uncommon thing, and I figured my fellows in this community would have experienced this issue, whether an incompatibility with an corporate OS mod or a matter of not getting a clean uninstall of one or another version of Office. Thanks for you help!

Comment: @Pete did you take a look at Ramhound's comment and my answer?

Comment: @Sun, I did. I'm not able to access the registry with Admin privileges, but I ran RegEdit with elevated privileges in the hopes it would be enough. I got a "there's no preview for this" message in the Preview pane, which I took as a good sign.

I literally just ran a fast repair of Office, and I've got previews!! Perfect!

Would you mind if I updated your answer with my experience including the additional steps I needed to take?

Comment: Yes please. Feel free to edit to clarify as there are more steps apparently.

Comment: Oh, and before I do, I was wondering why each key was given twice? (and the HKLME entry for PowerPoint is just a typo, yeah? Thanks again, everyone else I asked was stumped for a repair!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source: https://www.cyann.net/2015/07/10/solved-not-enough-memory-or-system-resources-to-start-office-preview/

To fix these errors and repair the preview pane, you need to remove the following registry keys, and you might need to follow up with a fast repair of Office.

Run Regedit as administrator or, if you can't run as administrator, try running with elevated privileges.

**Microsoft Excel previewer:**

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{00020827-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
```

**Microsoft PowerPoint previewer:**

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{65235197-874B-4A07-BDC5-E65EA825B718}
```

**Microsoft Word previewer:**

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{84F66100-FF7C-4fb4-B0C0-02CD7FB668FE}
```

**Microsoft Visio previewer:**

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{21E17C2F-AD3A-4b89-841F-09CFE02D16B7}
```